# returning weird dates function to calculate length of serice

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

My function below is working for some dates but not others some, its printing minus years for some reason ie., 365 days etc.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[hmsGetLosText](@FromDt as datetime) returns varchar(255)
as

BEGIN
DECLARE @YRS AS SMALLINT, @MNT AS SMALLINT, @DY AS SMALLINT, @Fvalue varchar(255)

SET @YRS = DATEDIFF(YY, @FromDt,GETDATE())
SET @MNT = DATEDIFF(MM, @FromDt,GETDATE()) % 12
SET @DY = (DATEDIFF(DD,GETDATE(), DATEADD(MM, (@YRS * 12) + @MNT,@FromDt) )*-1)


SET @Fvalue = CAST(@YRS AS VARCHAR) + ' y ' + CAST(@MNT AS VARCHAR) + ' m ' + CAST(@DY AS VARCHAR) + ' d '
RETURN @Fvalue
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of dates where it's not behaving correctly (and some where it does)

Comment: months with 31 days its causing it to be one day less i thought dateiff in .net would handle this properly but appears not

Comment: what is the `*-1` doing for the `DATEDIFF` in Setting `@DY`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

```
set @YRS = DATEDIFF(year,@FromDt,GETDATE()) +
        CASE WHEN DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,@FromDt,GETDATE()),@FromDt) > GETDATE()
             THEN -1 ELSE 0 END
set @FromDt = DATEADD(year,@YRS,@FromDt)

set @MNT = DATEDIFF(month,@FromDt,GETDATE()) +
        CASE WHEN DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,@FromDt,GETDATE()),@FromDt) > GETDATE()
             THEN -1 ELSE 0 END
set @FromDt = DATEADD(month,@MNT,@FromDt)

set @DY = DATEDIFF(day,@FromDt,GETDATE())
```

For me, these are far more readily understood - we first get a years value that we're happy with, then add that onto `@FromDt`. Then we can do a direct `DATEDIFF` for months without much fussing around with modulo arithmetic. Similarly, once we're happy with a months value, we adjust `@FromDt` again so that a simple `DATEDIFF` gives us the correct number of days.

(You can eliminate some further calculation by first setting `@YRS` and then working out whether to adjust it, but not sure if that's needed here)

---

The reason we have to do the slight fiddle around to get the correct `@YRS` and `@MNT` values is that [`DATEDIFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified *datepart* boundaries crossed between the specified *startdate* and *enddate*.

Which is to say, that `DATEDIFF(year,'20121231','20130101')` returns 1 (as does `DATEDIFF(year,'20120101','20131231')`). Which is correct per its own definition. But we want a value that never overshoots if we add that value back onto the earlier of the two dates - so we have to compensate by sometimes subtracting 1.

Comment: But if you have someone that is at 20/10/2013 and you take that away from today 5/11/2013 it should return 0 years 0 months 16 days the above does not